# How to make "location module" optional javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on javascript and php,I integrated "location module" means whenever i click on "button" then i am getting message "site allow to access your location", i want if i select "block" button then also "success function" should work, means i want to make "location module optional" so if i select "allow" or "block", further code (success/ajax) should work,Here is my current code

```
<button name="intime" class="in" >Clock in </button>




$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".in").click(function () {
            const options = {
                      enableHighAccuracy: true,
                      timeout: 5000,
                      maximumAge: 0
                    };
                    function success(pos) {
                      const crd = pos.coords;
                      var lats = crd.latitude;
                      var longs = crd.longitude;
                      var userId = <?php echo $ids=$_GET['eid']; ?>
                      
                       $.ajax({
                            //further code working
                        });
                    }

                    function error(err) {
                        var pathname = window.location.href;
                        }
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
        });


    });
```

Comment: _'i want if i select "block" button then also "success function" should work'_ - that is not possible. If the user blocks usage of GeoLocation, then the `success` callback simply won't be invoked, but only the `error` callback instead. The latter will get a `GeolocationPositionError` passed, with the `code` set to `1`, `PERMISSION_DENIED`. So you will have to make that AJAX request from within your error callback then in that situation.

Comment: Where are the buttons of which you speak? Just to clarify: If a user clicks on a `"Block"` button then the entire `geoLocation` code should be disregarded. If they click on `"Allow"` then the `geoLocation` will run and, with luck, the `success` callback will work?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius let me explain , I have a button and whenever i click on that button my ajax run and enter data into database so i just want to add user location (optional) so if i select "allow or block" then ajax should work and data should insert into database, hope you understand

Comment: @CBroe: let me explain: i tried to put ajax code inside "error fucntion" ( error condition) but ajax not worked for me because that time i am unable to get "lat long" ( inside error function ), hope you understand

Comment: The user would first have to decide whether or not to allow geolocation. If the user decides to **not** allow geolcation then no matter which button they press your `success` callback will not fire.

Comment: _"but ajax not worked for me because that time i am unable to get "lat long" ( inside error function )"_ - of course, because the user did not allow the use of the API that determines those in the first place. There simply _are_ no lat & long for you to do anything with in this case.

Comment: @CBroe understand but i just want my code should not stop means data should insert if i select "allow" or "block" , in short can i make "location module" optional ?

Comment: If the user has selected `block` or has disallowed `geolocation` what do you want to insert into the database?